# Spring MVC - can't load view after redirection

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I have a following simple Controller class with two methods:

```
@Controller
public class RegistrationController {

    private RegistrationService registrationService;

    @Autowired
    public RegistrationController(RegistrationService registrationService){
        this.registrationService = registrationService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public String register(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        registrationService.registerCustomer(customer);
        return "redirect:login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login() {
        System.out.println("Login page");
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Dispatcher servlet view resolver config:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

When I submit a request with json body on `/register` it properly registers new user, then it properly redirects to second method (in the console I can see "Login page") but then the view in the browser doesn't change to `login.jsp`. When I simply type localhost:8080/login it properly displays `login.jsp` page. I've also tried returning `new ModelAndView("login")`, but it didn't work either.

Comment: *property name="prefix">
        <value>/</value>
    </property>* this is why your page is not redirecting.. according to your **viewResolver** you are asking it to search jsp files in **/** directory with **.jsp** as suffix.  but i guess. you jsp files are in folder like _webapps/WEB-INF/jsp_ . Shortly.. change prefix directory.

Comment: No, jsp are in the / folder, thus why the localhost:8080/login properly shows login.jsp.

Comment: have you tested **"redirect:/login";**  ??

Comment: Yes, I did. The strange thing is that it enters the login method, but doesn't change the view in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Try to return "redirect:/login" instead of "redirect:login"

Option 2:Try giving a complete full path for the redirect, you can ideally return redirect:/login, this would redirect to a path relative to your web application root - http://example.com/appName/login